# Docker Searching Active directory users

Tags: model-view-controller, active-directory, aws-sdk, docker-machine

I am dockerizing an asp.net mvc app with base image microsoft/aspnet (framework 4.8). I am able to deploy the app in an Aws Ec2 instance and was able to launch the app successfully but search AD users module seems to be failing. C# Directory sevices is failing connect to Ldap service and getting service not found error. I am able to do this search using the same code from local Machine and from a console application hosted inside the server. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a network problem, like maybe a firewall blocking the connection, or simply no network path to your LDAP server.

Comment: I am able to qeary Ldap from same server through a console app